# Where is fail in rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have got url siter.ru/en.html

want to see site.ru/en/

I write in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html
```

But it gives to me 500 error, why?

Answer (score 0):

This is an endless loop you created!

The problem is that your rewritten URL *again* is matched by the RewriteRule, thus rewritten again and again in an endless loop. So you get something like: `site.ru/en.html.html.html.html`

Try adding a condition that prevents the second (and any further) attempts to rewrite the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.html$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  /$1.html
```

Comment: About `you can stop the rewriting process after the matching rule`: Are you serious?

Comment: @anubhava Well, trying not be act like a clown, but no one is too old to learn and gain insight about his failures in life. So I suggest you tell us what's wrong here! Thanks!

Comment: Even with `L` flag your rule will be matched again, and again, and again... That's why you must do like you did with a condition on `REQUEST_URI` (one way of doing it right)

Comment: @JustinIurman Is that so? I am confused by that... I always thought the `[L]` stops the rewriting process after the matching rule which is what the OP needs here. Obviously the rule will match again in _other_ requests, but I doubt you refer to that. So you want to say that although the `[L]` stops the rewriting process it _still_ reiterates?

Comment: `L` flag stops the rewrite process so other rules (next rules) won't be evaluated. For example, if i go to `http://domain.tld/page` then *mod_rewrite* forwards it to `/page.html` (and it leaves if `L` flag is present). But when it forwards to `/page.html`, *mod_rewrite* runs again and iterates over rules. Do you see where infinite loop is ?

Comment: @JustinIurman Sorry, you are probably right, but it is against my own experiences... Why whould the module iterate again? Note that this is _not_ an external redirection which creates a subsequent (separate) request. So I do _not_ see why this is a loop.

Comment: @arkascha: Just understand that `mod_rewrite` always runs in a loop and stops ONLY when all rules fail to run. Only `END` flag in Apache 2.4+ can end this loop. `L` flag merely acts like `continue` in a loop.

Comment: Thank for pointing that out! I made a short test and indeed that is a problem. Wonder why I never ran into that issue myself?!? I removed that second option from the answer for now. Thanks again!